# GoogleApiClient is not working in marshmallow and above devices?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

Am using googleapi client for getting user location it is working fine below marshmallow devices but on marshmallow devices application getting crashed don't know the reason can someone help me out let me post my code this is the activity am trying to get location:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.PeriodicTask;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static precisioninfomatics.backgroundgps.MyLocationService.TASK_GET_LOCATION_PERIODIC;

public class GPS extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GetMethod {
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    private AsyncTaskGet asyncTaskGet;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
        if (!checkPlayServices()) {
            finish();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        startService(new Intent(this, GPSService.class));
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
       btnFusedLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnFusedLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                    String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
                    String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
                    String userID = "1";
                    String time = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    String url = "http://172.16.6.106:8080/gpstracker/api/coordinates/" + lat + "/" + lng + "/" + userID + "/" + time;
                    Log.d("url", url);
                    GetNoteList(getApplicationContext());
                    asyncTaskGet.execute(url);

                }
            }
        });
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                        builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    GPS.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        startPeriodicLocationTask();

    }

    public void startPeriodicLocationTask() {
        Log.d("periodictask", "startPeriodicLocationTask");
        GcmNetworkManager mGcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);
        PeriodicTask taskBuilder = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
                .setService(MyLocationService.class)
                .setTag(TASK_GET_LOCATION_PERIODIC)
                .setPeriod(30).setFlex(20)
                .setPersisted(true).build();
        mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(taskBuilder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                    "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                    "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                    "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                    "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }

    public void GetNoteList(Context context) {
        asyncTaskGet = new AsyncTaskGet(context);
        asyncTaskGet.getMethod = this;
    }

    @Override
    public Void getDataFromServer(String objects) {
        Log.d("response", objects);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.d("nogps", "nogps");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My gradle:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'

     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I think am making mistake in googleplay service  am using late googleplay service version can somebody help me to solve this issue!!

Comment: Heard of **Runtime permissions** for marshmallow and above devices ? :)

Comment: For Marshmallow os version. Need to ask user for Location permission.  In your code you didn't added code for permission. It may be a reason for crash. Also provide the crash log.

Comment: i tested on real device so cannot obtain crash report may be on geterror dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime permissions are your issue, in Android M and above google added the need to request for permissions when they are needed (like in iOS).

See this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

There are many wrappers around to make adding permissions easier on sites like https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235?category=1

Here is some code, taken from android developers site to help you along:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
}
```